# Jasmine.d.ts failing to compile in visual studio with error "jasmine.d.ts(137,44): error TS1005: ',' expected"

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, jasmine, definitelytyped

I am using VisualStudio 2013 + chutzpah to run jasmine tests ( in Typescript)

I installed `jasmine.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped`(v1.9.8) and `JasmineTest` (v2.2.0) packages

The file with the test itself transpiles to javascript ok but when I run the test i get this error

```
 ...path/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts(137,44): error TS1005: ',' expected
```

doing a `tsc -v` in the project folder i get

```
message TS6029: Version 1.7.5
```

I am suspecting it is something to do with tsc version, or the package i have installed.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That line contains a *union type*: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/70bf7e2bfeb0d5b1b651ef3219bcc65c8eec117e/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts#L137

`| string`

That is a tell tale sign that the TypeScript tools for your visual studio are out dated.

The `tsc -v` you are seeing in the console is not the one being used by VS. Try reinstalling the **VS Tools for TypeScript**.